# How can I change the label elevation of a material ui TextField?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to elevate the label of a textfield but I cant, this is my code.

```
  textStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#1c1a1a',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 0,
    width: 400,
    height: 66,
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 10,
    padding: '0 10px',
    '& .MuiFormLabel-root': {
      color: 'grey',
      padding: '1px',
      height:'10px',
    },
  },
```

height does nothing, how can I elevate the label?

Comment: `marginTop: -10`

Comment: Thanks!! I have been searching the whole morning!

Comment: Glad I could help, please upvote and accept the answer. It will help your reputation too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this field to your `textStyle`:

```
marginTop: -10
```